# Как обработать строку из реестра

Tags: c#

Всех приветствую, вот небольшую задачку делаю. Достаю из реестра данных о файлах запускающихся при старте системы. В коде, я достаю имя файла, достаю путь этого файла, и там еще в строке где путь, есть параметры запуска. Можно ли как то эти параметры достать из реестра отдельно, или нужно разбирать строку, например регексом или еще как.

```
// в методе Main()
     RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
            var so = rk.OpenSubKey("Software");
            var mk = so.OpenSubKey("Microsoft");
            var win = mk.OpenSubKey("Windows");
            var Currver = win.OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion");
            var RUN = Currver.OpenSubKey("Run");
            PrintKeys(RUN);// из реестра автозагрузка


// собственно сам метод
 static void PrintKeys(RegistryKey rkey)
        {
            int caunt = rkey.ValueCount;
            String[] names = rkey.GetValueNames();
            string[] keys = new string[caunt];
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                keys[i] = (string)rkey.GetValue(names[i]);
            }

            int icount = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Subkeys of " + rkey.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");

            // Print the contents of the array to the console.
            foreach (String s in keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}--{1}",names[icount],keys[icount]);


                icount++;
                if (icount >= 100)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верно понимаю суть изложенного автором вопроса, то решение можно, скажем, представить так:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;

internal sealed class Program {
   static void Main() {
      String rp = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";

      using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(rp)) {
         if (null == rp) return;
         var e = rk.GetValueNames().Select(n => new {
            Name = n, Value = rk.GetValue(n),
            Exec = rk.GetValue(n).ToString()
                     .Split('"').Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).First()
         });
         foreach (var x in e)
            Console.WriteLine(
               "Name: {0}\nPath: {1}\nExec: {2}\n", x.Name, x.Value, x.Exec
            );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Супер, то что нужно

Comment: Если мы имеем вот такой адрес, для Local machine  string folder = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\startupfolder\";  это папка вроде для автозагрузки именно самой папки в винде. Код ваш выкидывает исключение.

Comment: А можно ли с помощью вашего метода также еще в добавок ко всему вытащить параметры командной строки для запуска файла?

Comment: Если не затруднит, уточните версию Windows, в которой замечен ключ реестра ```SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\startupfolder```, а также уточните что именно подразумевалось под ```папка вроде для автозагрузки```.

Comment: Параметры командной строки запущенного в системе процесса извлекаются из PEB самого процесса; доступные аргументы запуска приложения (аргументы командной строки) могут быть извлечены по-разному, например, попыткой чтения справочного руководства из ```stdout```.

Comment: По сути это win7 64 разряда, вообще мне нужно узнать как вытащить файлы, которые загружаются при загрузке винды из папки автозагрузки и из планировщика